# Having trouble with the integral of the second derivative of the function $e^{\frac{-1}{1 - x^2}}$ after a change of variables

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, change-of-variable, mathematica

The first thing I have to note is that I am not 100% sure whether this problem is due to Mathematica or just the mathematics I have produced. Thus feel free to direct me to the appropriate forum.

Let $f(x) = e^{\frac{-1}{1 - x^2}}$, $g(x) = \frac{d^2f(x)}{dx^2}$. Then $g(x)^2$ has a finite area as is confirmed by the picture below:
[image]

Due to a specific example I am working with I need to use change of variables $u = \frac{\pi}{4}x$ so that $f$'s domain would be $\left(\frac{-\pi}{4}, \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$ and $f(u) = e^{\frac{-1}{1 - \left(\frac{4x}{\pi}\right)^2}}$.

As I am not that savy with Mathematica I reckoned that it would take me less time to compute everything with $f(u)$ than with $f(x)$ and somehow have Mathematica to perform the change of variables.

What I end up with is (where I am using the symbol $x$ instead of $u$)
[image]

which isn't at all what I wanted. Is there some subtlety I am overlooking why else wouldn't the integral evaluate after the change of variables?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a problem with the input in Mathematica.

With Wolfram for the second integral I've obtained ([second derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=second%20derivative%20e%5E%28-1%2F%281-16x%5E2%2Fpi%5E2%29%29) and [integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int%20%284%2Fpi%29*%28%2832%20e%5E%28%CF%80%5E2%2F%28-%CF%80%5E2%20%2B%2016%20x%5E2%29%29%20%CF%80%5E2%20%28-%CF%80%5E4%20%2B%20768%20x%5E4%29%29%2F%28-%CF%80%5E2%20%2B%2016%20x%5E2%29%5E4%29%5E2%20dx%2C%20x%3D-pi%2F4..pi%2F4)):
[image]
For the latter integral the numerical value corresponds to the first one up to a factor of $(\pi/4)^4$ ([integral)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int%20%28pi%2F4%29%5E4*%284%2Fpi%29*%28%2832%20e%5E%28%CF%80%5E2%2F%28-%CF%80%5E2%20%2B%2016%20x%5E2%29%29%20%CF%80%5E2%20%28-%CF%80%5E4%20%2B%20768%20x%5E4%29%29%2F%28-%CF%80%5E2%20%2B%2016%20x%5E2%29%5E4%29%5E2%20dx%2C%20x%3D-pi%2F4..pi%2F4):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did not have any problem
$$f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}}\quad \implies \quad g(x)=f''(x)=\frac{2(3 x^4-1)}{\left(x^2-1\right)^4}e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}}$$ and numerical integration gives
$$\int_{-\frac \pi 4}^{+\frac \pi 4} \Bigg[\frac{2(3 x^4-1)}{\left(x^2-1\right)^4}e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}} \Bigg]^2\,dx=1.8340764522074691939818132792902350094\cdots$$

Without any specific option (except the `WorkingPrecision`, I did not have any problem to get $500^+$ decimal places.

Even if it does not mean anything, a good approximation (absolute error of $2.9\times 10^{-7}$) is
$$\frac{150 \left(1-2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}{1+3 \sqrt{e}}$$

Comment: Are you sure that your second derivative is correct? I think that the form should be $e^{\frac{-1}{1 - x^2}}\cdot (\text{sum of three different terms})$